# Case expression does not return the "else" value in Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql, rails-postgresql, case-expression

I'm creating a SQL query with a lot of nested queries and I'm trying to use the CASE expression but it is behaving weirdly.

This is my query at the moment:

```
select t.fpl_id, t.team_name,
sum(pf.points)as gwpts,
(
    select sum(transfers_malus)
    from gameweeks
    where gameweeks.team_id = t.id and gameweeks.number = g.number
)as malus,
(
    select sum(points)
    from player_fixtures as pfix
    where gw_number = g.number and pfix.player_id = CASE WHEN minutes_played > 0 THEN g.captain_id ELSE g.vice_captain_id END
)
as cpts,
 (
    select max(web_name)
    from players
    join player_fixtures on players.id = player_fixtures.player_id and gw_number = g.number
    where players.id = CASE WHEN player_fixtures.minutes_played > 0 THEN g.captain_id ELSE g.vice_captain_id END
) as captain_name,
array_agg(p.id) as lineup
from teams as t
join gameweeks as g on t.id  = g.team_id
join gameweeks_players as gp on gp.gameweek_id = g.id
join players as p on gp.player_id = p.id
join player_fixtures as pf on p.id = pf.player_id  and pf.gw_number = g.number
where t.id = 1
group by t.id, g.id
order by g.number asc
```

The bit where I have a problem is when I'm doing the case statement to see if one of the player ( the captain ) hasn't played based on "minutes_played":

```
(select sum(points)
    from player_fixtures as pfix
    where gw_number = g.number and pfix.player_id = CASE WHEN minutes_played > 0 THEN g.captain_id ELSE g.vice_captain_id END
) as cpts
```

and

```
 (
    select max(web_name)
    from players
    join player_fixtures on players.id = player_fixtures.player_id and gw_number = g.number
    where players.id = CASE WHEN player_fixtures.minutes_played > 0 THEN g.captain_id ELSE g.vice_captain_id END
) as captain_name,
```

When minutes_played is indeed greater than 0, everything works fine. However, when it is equal to 0 it just doesn't "return" anything and I get a NULL in return in my row. minutes_played is an integer and when I try with the following script on the player_fixtures where minutes_played is = 0 my > evaluation works and I get the correct "BAD".

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
    BEGIN
        IF (select minutes_played from player_fixtures where gw_number = 19 and player_id = 266 ) > 0 THEN 
            RAISE NOTICE 'GOOD';
        ELSE
            RAISE NOTICE 'BAD';
        END IF;
    END;
$$;
```

I'm pretty new at this whole DB thing so I'm probably making a rookie mistake but I've been trying for the past 6hours without any luck. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What happens if you use alias in your case statement, like e.g. for the first one: `CASE WHEN pfix.minutes_played > 0 THEN g.captain_id ELSE g.vice_captain_id END`

Comment: @cha already tried with alias everywhere or no alias, didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when there are no rows that match, `sum()` returns a null, *and* no comparison with null is ever true.

Instead, use `exists()`, for example:

```
where exists(select * from player_fixtures
    where gw_number = 19
    and player_id = 266 
    and minutes_played > 0)
```

or you can use `if exists(...) then` in a stored proc.